# Why do i get naming error using -cp function in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, meilisearch

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir Kolokwium
cd Kolokwium
touch Kolokwium.tex
mkdir Baza_danych
cd Baza_danych
echo Bartosz Obstawski >> Dane.txt
echo "SELECT * FROM city WHERE countryCode='POL' AND Population > 260000 AND Population < 300000;" >> Dane.sql
cd ..
mkdir Obraz
cd Obraz
cp -r /home/share/informatyka_3/drop/drop-001.jpg /home/student/stud42/Kolokwium/Obraz | mv drop-001.jpg Obraz.jpg
convert -pointsize 50 -draw "text 25,60 'Wtorek 14-16'" Obraz.jpg Obraz.jpg
cd ..
mkdir Dokumenty
cd Dokumenty
mkdir Bartosz
mkdir Obstawski

\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\author{Bartosz Obstawski}
\title{Dokumentacja}
\date{7.06.2022}
\maketitle
\newpage
\begin{enumerate}
\item{Kolokwium}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item{Kolokwium.tex}
    \item{Baza danych}
        \begin{enumerate}
        \item{Dane.txt}
        \item{Dane.sql}
        \end{enumerate}
    \item{Obraz}
        \begin{enumerate}
        \item{Obraz.jpg}
        \end{enumerate}
    \item{Dokumenty}
        \begin{enumerate}
        \item{Bartosz}
        \item{Obstawski}
        \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth]{/home/student/stud42/Kolokwium/Obraz/Obraz.jpg}
\centering
\caption{Obraz z kolokwium}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

And i got problem with comment cp, what i did wrong ? I got many wrong asweres before but i didnt get exact question, could you please help me with this lorem imasfhmpgavinoupoTTNFPAOYC RAMFCOWREIYSVPAPNUTNVQA naiovtrn;as rcansyu vaenayp avtnacyp
And i got problem with comment cp, what i did wrong ? I got many wrong asweres before but i didnt get exact question, could you please help me with this lorem imasfhmpgavinoupoTTNFPAOYC RAMFCOWREIYSVPAPNUTNVQA naiovtrn;as rcansyu vaenayp avtnacyp
And i got problem with comment cp, what i did wrong ? I got many wrong asweres before but i didnt get exact question, could you please help me with this lorem imasfhmpgavinoupoTTNFPAOYC RAMFCOWREIYSVPAPNUTNVQA naiovtrn;as rcansyu vaenayp avtnacyp

Comment: Please don't repeat text or add garbage to your question if the system prompts you to add more information. Adding random stuff to circumvent the quality filter will likely result in you getting downvoted, your question closed, and potentially getting banned for attempting to circumvent the rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem today, you have to use the scp command instead.